# Any way to edit sass/scss file from styles tab in Chrome DevTools

Tags: css, sass, google-chrome-devtools, sass-maps

Editing sass/scss is working via source maps **only through code editor** in devtools.

But when i make changes in elements -> styles tab, these changes are not saved to sass/scss file.

For example, if I change `border-radius` to another value, it will not be saved to scss file.
[image]

Here is my scss code

```
.SiteBuilder .e-row__select {
  position: relative;

  &:after {
    content: '';
  }

  select {
    border-radius: 4px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The styles you see from inspector are coming only from **css** files.

You can see the "sass/scss" source for each css property because there is a `*.css.map` associated with the current css file. The `*.css.map` file is generated from the sass compiler.

**Every change you make on the Styles tab is not saved anywhere.**

In order to make css changes you could use Chrome Devtools "**Local Overrides**" or "**Workspaces**". But even on this case you could edit the css or scss files from the Sources tab, not from the inspector.

Comment: Please notice the green circle in my screenshot, this means local overrides are active.
When I am using css (not sass), every change I make is successfully saved from the Styles tab, but it sucks when you cant change sass code where I already have source maps generated.

Comment: @AamirR, where you able to manage a way to make Local Overrides work in sass files?